# Sorting with multiple conditions in QDir::entryInfoList

Tags: c++, sorting, qt4, qdir

[Qt's doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#SortFlag-enum) says that `QDir::entryInfoList` can accept multiple sorting conditions but how to do is unclear to me.

```
This enum describes the sort options available to QDir, e.g. for entryList() and entryInfoList(). 
The sort value is specified by OR-ing together values from the following list: 

QDir::Name  0x00    Sort by name.
QDir::Time  0x01    Sort by time (modification time).
:
(snip)
```

I assume `OR-ing` needs to be done somehow by can't think of how for now (I think have to go back and review bit-shifting?) but could someone tell me how? Appreciate it.

(Anyway this description isn't clear as a document for high-level language?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDir::SortFlags` is actually a typedef of `QFlags<QDir::SortFlag>`, type-safe way of storing OR-combinations of enum values.

So what you do is simply `QDir::Name | QDir::Time` in your case as the argument to `QDir::entryInfoList()` method.

Comment: How could you use more than two 'sorts'?

Comment: Then you simply OR together more values.